# Firebase Web Регистрация

Tags: firebase

Как сделать регистрацию пользователей через web-страницу на моем хостинге? Нужен пример готового рабочего кода, где я заменю данные конфига на свои.
Пользователь переходит на страницу где ему нужно ввести логин и пароль и нажимает кнопку регистрация, после этого его данные появляются у меня в админке в Firebase Authentication.